# Update a DropDrownList in a ASP.NET MVC when a user select un option in another DropDrownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

Anyone known how to polulate a combo with values that depends on the user seleccion, I have to combo, Country and Region, When the user select contry I need to go to the database  and get the region of the country, Anyone knwows how to do this, if posibile using AJAX.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you need to use a particular Ajax libarary?

The Ajax.Net Control Toolkit has the [Cascading Dropdown](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx) control pre-built for this functionality.

---

Missed the MVC part, in which case the Ajax Control Toolkit won't work. jQuery is probably the best option, since it makes Ajax extremely easy to code and MS is officially supporting it in conjunction with the MVC framework.

If you created a RESTful service on your site (there should be plenty of documentation on how to do this) you can return a json response through jQuery like this:

The markup:

```
<select id="opt1">
  <option value='1'>Option 1</option>
  <option value='2'>Option 2</option>
</select>

<select id="opt2" disabled></select>
```

Assuming the service will accept 'id' as a parameter and return a json object using this schema for example:

```
[
  { name: 'option1', value: '1'},
  { name: 'option2', value: '2'}
]
```

You'd add this javascript to the page:

```
$(function() {
  $('select#opt1').change(function(){
    $.getJSON('/data/myservice',{id: this.value},
      function(response) {
        var options = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          options += "<option value='" + response[i].value + "'>"
                  +  response[i].name + "</option>";
        }
        $('select#opt2').removeAttr('disabled').html(options);
      });
  });
});
```

A quick explanation of what's going on there; jQuery code can be a bit like peeling an onion, so I'll take it a level at a time:

`$(function(){})` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){})`, so it runs the function when the ready event fires.

`$('select#opt1').change(function(){})` finds the `<select>` named 'opt1' and runs the function when the change event fires.

`$.getJSON()` does the Ajax call for you. JSON responses are returned as strings, and have to be parsed into JSON objects, which $.getJSON does for you automatically. The first field is the url of the service, the second is a name/value pair that is converted to a querystring, and the third is the callback function to handle the response.

Comment: I read the asp.net ajax control toolkit does not play nicely with asp.net MVC.  It works great with webforms though.

Comment: Ah, I missed the MVC requirement

Comment: Instead of {id: this.val()} I have to use {id: this.value}

Comment: Corrected. I was thinking of $(this).val() but this.value is better.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using jQuery and MVC's JsonResult to achieve this functionality. Have something in your Model to grab the new info from the db based on the given user input. The JsonResult will return this back to the view and you'll use jQuery will populate the drop down accordingly.

A very [basic example using jQuery and the MVC framework's JsonResult](http://www.dev102.com/2008/08/19/jquery-and-the-aspnet-mvc-framework/) is available [here](http://www.dev102.com/2008/08/19/jquery-and-the-aspnet-mvc-framework/)

Answer (score 0):

I also would recommend jQuery, Json actions are useful if you go and get the data asynchronously.  The final result will be a chained combo box setup, there are lots of examples on how to do this in jQuery, [this one is fairly good with a live demo and the code.](http://www.codeassembly.com/Simple-chained-combobox-plugin-for-jQuery/)  Hopefully it would help you.